# How do you webpack bundle assets into html file inline/embed?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Is it possible for webpack to accept an html file as an entry point, parse the html file for css, images, js and write the contents of said files into the html file? So the css & js will be plain text while the images will be in base64.

Thanks.